# Cannot access to Baseuri C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Since i moved all my methods to classes, i can't get access to Baseuri that represents the base URI for an XAML-constructed object at XAML load time. This property is useful for URI resolution at run time. Here are some pictures to describe my problem.

Here is my code-behind, which is connected to XAML.

[image]

I need to get the base URI for an XAML-constructed object.
[image]

Thanks for all!

Comment: Have you tried to make DisplayTheWorld non-static? And unless the class somewhere inherits a WPF class (I see you made it partial), it has no way to determine where BaseUri comes from

Comment: I made DisplayTheWord non-static, nothing happened. How could i determine where the Baseuri comes from?

Comment: Did you try to just remove this parameter? Where your images are stored?

Comment: When i removed this parameter, i got an exception - Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. My images are stored in Assets.

Comment: @M.Kesküll If the code used to be in another class, then the property comes from that class. I'd guess Hangman needs to inherit from Window (like in class Hangman : Window)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, the code used to be in another class. I needed to make my code more abstract, so i moved my methods from MainPage(HangMan) to classes, so i could access methods by classes, like it is on my first picture DisplayWord.DisplayTheWord(); I know that i need to get access to the base URI for an XAML-constructed object.

Comment: You can pass baseurl through a parameter. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). If your images are store in the same directory that your application you can compute the base url from ```System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location```

Comment: @M.Kesküll mixing UI code and logic is almost always a bad idea. Either make the method receive the baseuri or put it in a class that inherits from Window for further re-use.

Comment: Can you post that `BaseUri` property you are using in that class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How can i make the method receive the baseuri?

Comment: Change the method to DisplayTheWord(string baseUir)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I sent you an e-mail.

Comment: @M.Kesküll The problem is that you must remove the static qualifier from DisplayTheWord

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If i remove the static qualifier from DisplayTheWord, then i can't get access to DisplayTheWord method on my MainPage.

Comment: That's because you need an instance of Hangman. So, either make DisplayTheWord an instance method (remove static) or make it receive BaseUri through parameter

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I got it, i made an instance of HangMan, i got access to Baseuri(i think) but i need to access that method in MainPage to make my game work.